# Why do some answers have dofollow links while others don't?

Tags: discussion

Why do some answers have dofollow links - like this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87262/39924

[image]

while others don't (for example, https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/310057/39924, notice `nofollow` ) ?

[image]